# Combine similar rows based on timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT Name, Text as Value, UpdateDate from A WHERE UserID = @userId
UNION 
SELECT Name, STR(Value), UpdateDate FROM B WHERE UserID = @userId
```

Tables `A` and `B` both may or may not have a row for a given name. Where they both have a Name, I only want my result set to have the newest row in it.

Currently my result set will look something like this:

```
Name | Value | UpdateDate
Foo    '23'    Jan-1-2012
Foo    'A'     Feb-7-2013
Bar    '42'    Jan-3-2011
```

And I would like to condense that down to:

```
Name | Value
Foo    'A'
Bar    '42'
```

I realize I could do this fairly easily in the client, but it would be really awesome if some kind of `Group-By` magic could do it in a single query. Hopefully it wouldn't be too expensive either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH unionTB
AS
(
    SELECT Name, Text as Value, UpdateDate 
    from A WHERE UserID = @userId
    UNION 
    SELECT Name, STR(Value), UpdateDate 
    FROM B WHERE UserID = @userId
),
recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  Name, Value, UpdateDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name
                                ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) rn
    FROM    unionTB
)
SELECT  Name, Value, UpdateDate
FROM    recordList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dd29/1)